# Elasticsearch: Found the deleted document?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing a problem: I can find the deleted document right after I deleted it.

But when I wait for seconds, the deleted document is just gone and I cannot find the document by using the same command.

In fact, I knew there is something similar when post a new document, you need to wait a while to be able to find it. I think it's acceptable for me.
But about this case, any ideas?

Here is the reproducible gist: https://gist.github.com/hxuanji/89813ffe0979f12dba66

In the gist, after I deleted the document, I try to XHEAD the document, I received 404 which means it had been deleted.  So far so good.

But next I try to query it, I actually can find the deleted document. Here is the problem.  And then I sleep 2 sec, query the same search command again, the deleted document is just gone.

It seems there are some contradictions between HEAD and _search.

Any suggestions of this situation ? Is this situation normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It if is important to be reproduceable, [refresh](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) after the `DELETE`.  This makes the change at once (no need to wait for it so ES flushes/refreshes the changes)

Comment: Yes, this can work when I refresh for each deletion. The root cause might be the GET API is realtime other than the other APIs. But I am considering when to manually perform refresh API. Anyway, thanks for your help.