# Elasticsearch document still found after deletion?

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch, axios

I have an API running with express. I have two resources (search and delete).
I am running a query for deleting a document. After deletion the success of deletion is logged to the console. **After** the deletion request is done, I run another request against the API to refresh a list in the UI. The documents still contain the prior deleted document (which definetely was deleted, because I got teh response from ES that it is deleted). I assure, the search is ran after the deletion. And it still contains the prior deleted document.

When I run the **same** search query again, the deleted document does not appear in the document anymore.

The question now is... Is it my fault? Is it a caching issue from the ES.js library? Is it a timing issue with lucene handling the deletion?

Some environment information:

**Backend**: express ^4.13.3, using express-promise-router ^2.0.0, node 8.1.2

**Frontend**: axios 0.16.2

Here are my rest resources:

```
api.get('/searchDocuments', async (req, res) => {
    const result = await DocumentService.searchDocuments(req.query.searchQuery, req.query.from || 0, req.query.size || 10);
    console.log(result.search.hits);
    res.reply({
        search: {
            hits: result.search.hits.total,
            data: result.search.hits.hits.map(hit => hit._source)
        }
    });
});

api.delete('/:documentId', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Deleting document ${req.params.documentId}`);
    const result = await DocumentService.deleteDocument(req.params.documentId);
    console.log(`Done deleting document ${req.params.documentId}: ${result}`);
    if (result && result.found) {
        res.reply(undefined, 'deleted');
    } else {
        res.reply('not found', 404);
    }
});
```

And here is the code from my services:

```
async searchDocuments(searchQuery: string, from: number = 0, size: number = 10) {
    const result = {};
    const operations = [];
    const query = {
        index: 'documents',
        body: {
            from: from * size,
            size: size
        }
    };
    if (searchQuery) {
        const targetFields = [
            'title^4',
            'tags^5',
            'metadata.key^2',
            'metadata.value^3',
            '_all'
        ];
        query.body.query = {
            simple_query_string : {
                query: searchQuery,
                analyzer: 'simple',
                fields: targetFields,
                default_operator: 'and'
            }
        };

        operations.push(async () => {
            result.suggestions = await ElasticsearchService.wrap(
                ElasticsearchService.client.search({
                    index: 'documents',
                    body: {
                        size: 0,
                        aggs: {
                            autocomplete: {
                                terms: {
                                    field: 'autocomplete',
                                    order: {
                                        _count: 'desc'
                                    },
                                    include: {
                                        pattern: `${searchQuery}.*`
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        query: {
                            prefix: {
                                autocomplete: {
                                    value: searchQuery
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            )
        });

    }
    operations.push(async () => {
        result.search = await ElasticsearchService.wrap(
            ElasticsearchService.client.search(query)
        );
    });

    await Promise.all(operations.map(o => o()));
    return result;
}

async deleteDocument(documentId: string) {
    const document = await this.getDocument(documentId);
    const deleteTagActions = [];
    if (document && document.found) {
        for (const tag of document._source.tags) {
            deleteTagActions.push((async () => {
                const tagCountResult = await TagService.countDocumentsWithTag(tag);
                if (tagCountResult.count === 1) {
                    await TagService.deleteTag(tag);
                    console.log(`Deleting tag ${tag}`);
                }
            })());
        }
    }
    await Promise.all(deleteTagActions);
    return await ElasticsearchService.wrap(
        ElasticsearchService.client.delete({
            index: 'documents',
            type: 'documents',
            id: documentId
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in a related question. A little change to my code made the trick - after deletion I simply refresh the index because the deletion was not yet flushed (GET is realtime, some other APIs are not).

[Elasticsearch: Found the deleted document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25525474/elasticsearch-found-the-deleted-document)